# Java Method Needs Condensing

Tags: java

How can I condense this method to look more clean? It works perfect how it is, just looks extremely ugly, has no elegance. I'm sure there's a better way to go about doing this I just can't find it.

```
public class ItemProfitComparator implements Comparator<MenuItem>{
  public int compare(MenuItem menuVar1, MenuItem menuVar2) 
  {
     if( ((menuVar1.getTotalSales() - (menuVar1.getNumOrders()*menuVar1.getWholesaleCost())) - (menuVar2.getTotalSales() - (menuVar2.getNumOrders()*menuVar2.getWholesaleCost()))) > 0){
      return (int)Math.ceil(((menuVar1.getTotalSales() - (menuVar1.getNumOrders()*menuVar1.getWholesaleCost())) - (menuVar2.getTotalSales() - (menuVar2.getNumOrders()*menuVar2.getWholesaleCost()))));
     }else if(((menuVar1.getTotalSales() - (menuVar1.getNumOrders()*menuVar1.getWholesaleCost())) - (menuVar2.getTotalSales() - (menuVar2.getNumOrders()*menuVar2.getWholesaleCost()))) < 0){
      return (int)Math.floor(((menuVar1.getTotalSales() - (menuVar1.getNumOrders()*menuVar1.getWholesaleCost())) - (menuVar2.getTotalSales() - (menuVar2.getNumOrders()*menuVar2.getWholesaleCost()))));
     }else{
      return 0;
     } 
  }

}
```

Comment: You're calculating the same expression over and over again.  Factor it out into a variable.

Comment: How about local variables? Don't try to press everything into one statement.

Comment: This may be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (be sure to read their help page before posting to ensure you stay within the scope of the site). It's off-topic for SO because it's a code question without a specific solvable problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be on the Code Review, please take my question down.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable to store the result of your calculation:

```
public class ItemProfitComparator implements Comparator<MenuItem> {
    public int compare(MenuItem menuVar1, MenuItem menuVar2) {
        double res = menuVar1.getTotalSales() - (menuVar1.getNumOrders() * menuVar1.getWholesaleCost())) - (menuVar2.getTotalSales() - (menuVar2.getNumOrders() * menuVar2.getWholesaleCost()));

        if (res > 0) {
            return (int) Math.ceil(res);
        } else if (res < 0) {
            return (int) Math.floor(res);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, for code review, there is a separate [site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, and sorry! I didn't actually realize there was a different site for that!

Comment: Plus, to increase readability, you could refactor the variable assignment into multiple variables.

Comment: I would even press enter right before or after that middle `-` sign, and align it so you can see that the two halfs are the same (except var1 vs var2).

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's true. This single line might be expressed within a couple of lines to increase readability.

Comment: Or yeah, and drop the two `else`. And return 1 and -1.

Answer (score 3):

As others point out you can improve this by using local variables.

Also, your use of `floor` and `ceil` is unnecessary. All that matters is the sign of the answer. To compare two `double` values you can do

```
if (a > b) {
    return 1;
} else if (a < b) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

However, you are much better of just doing

```
return Double.compare(a, b);
```

Note that Java 8 introduced `Comparator.comparingDouble(...)` for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Could you expand further on implementation towards what I have?

Comment: @LearningProcess Are you using Java 8?

Comment: In that case, I would just use @meriton's code, except I would use `comparingDouble` instead of `comparing`.

Answer (score 1):

A comparator is much easier to write using a lambda:

```
Comparator<MenuItem> profitComparator = Comparator.comparing(
    (menuItem) -> menuItem.getTotalSales() - (menuItem.getNumOrders() * menuItem.getWholesaleCost())
);
```